# Initializer type JQuery<TElement> is not assignable to variable type JQuery

Tags: jquery, typescript, phpstorm, webstorm, typescript-typings

This is an error that we seem to be getting in PhpStorm every time we initialise `$(this)` in a jQuery each loop. After hours/days of research I haven't managed to find any information about why PhpStorm is flagging this as an error.

We use `typescript-eslint-parser` for linting, which is not flagging up any errors.

Is this just a problem with PhpStorm, or is it a genuine TypeScript error?

Can it be solved or ignored?

These are the types that are installed:

```
"@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
"@types/bootstrap": "3.3.36",
"@types/node": "8.5.1",
"@types/jquery": "3.2.7",
"@types/qs": "^6.5.1",
```

```js
$.fn.extend({
    performanceCharts: function (): JQuery {
        'use strict'
        $(this).each(function (): void {
            let $this: JQuery = $(this)
        });
    }
})

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.js-performance-charts').performanceCharts()
})
```

```html
<div class="js-performance-charts"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: To me, both PhpStorm and tsc compiler report 2 errors for your code: `missing return statement for non-void method` (`TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value. `) and `unresolved function` (`TS2339: Property 'performanceCharts' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.`). I can't see `Initializer type JQuery<TElement> is not assignable to variable type JQuery` errors (PhpStorm 2017.3.1, built 173.3942)

Comment: Thanks for testing the code, but it was just a quick snippet of our plugin to show what the code is supposed to do, which is why there are errors from the things I missed (sorry). I have solved the problem after I updated PhpStorm from 2017.1 to 2017.3 (after spotting your version number). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: This must have been a problem with the version of PhpStorm. The problem disappeared after upgrading from 2017.1 to 2017.3.